# SVN Diff File names getting changed in windows

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Our SVN is installed in a unix machine. When I give queries from a Windows machine, files are not displaying properly. Spaces and # characters in the file name result in junk characters in Windows. For Example:

> svn diff --summarize -r 54858:54983 http://abc.com:18080/svn/12.0.0/branches/Project1/SOFT
>
> M       htt://abc.com:18080/svn/12.0.0/branches/Project1/SOFT/MAIN/FP/SPC/fppks_rule_gen.spc
>
> M      htt://abc.com:18080/svn/12.0.0/branches/Project1/SOFT/MAIN/FP/SPC/fppk%23_prod_shell.spc
>
> M      htt://abc.com:18080/svn/12.0.0/branches/Project1/SOFT/MAIN/FP/SPC/fppk%23_ntwrk_shell.spc

Here the second and third files are `fppk#_prod_shell.spc` and `fppk#_ntwrk_shell.spc`, But in the above output it is shown as `fppk%23_prod_shell.spc` and `fppk%23_ntwrk_shell.spc` (%, 23 are all coming extra).

I have noticed this issue for files with Space also. Is there any way I can display these kind of files in Windows properly?

Comment: They are not junk characters. The file names have been encoded into [URL friendly formats](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).  `%23` is the url encoded value of `#`.  `23` is the hex value for `#`.